# Bootstrap 3 div order change on mobile view

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using BOOTSTRAP 3, I put 2 div(s):
1. `<div class="col-md-4">1</div>`
2. `<div class="col-md-8">2</div>`
Which looks like this :
[image]

Now, if I change the resolution to mobile or tablet view it looks like this :
 
[image]

The problem starts here for me. I want the order of div in mobile that `div[2]` on the top and `div[1]` on bottom.

> PS: I'm using `direction:rtl`.

Comment: Do you have any dir="rtl" in you html code? This may be causing you the issue?

Comment: Yes I am using `direction:rtl`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When designing responsive websites, always design **mobile-first**. which means your HTML code represents the layout on a mobile device.

So keep div[2] first, and div[1] second by default. And then change their behaviour on larger screen sizes.

So, you can modify your code as follows:-

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-8 col-md-push-4">2</div>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4 col-md-pull-8">1</div>
```

On mobile, both divs have equal widths, and div[2] will appear before div[1](referring to your diagram). But on desktop and above, div[2] will be pushed to the right, and div[1] will be pulled to the left, resulting in the desired order.

Hope this helps! :-)

Answer (score 1):

When using rigth to left direction in bootstrap you will need to create a custom bootstrap css for alignments where you shall make stylings for classes `float:right` rather than left

This can be a hard task, depending on you css knowledge.

You can also check this library which may help [bootstrap rtl](https://github.com/morteza/bootstrap-rtl).